# Can we write scalar potential associated with a Vector Function?

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

If we are given a vector function, can we directly write its associated scalar potential? Should there be some other "cross" terms too?

Let's take a Vector function $$\vec A(x, y, z) = (4xy-3x^2z^2)\hat{i} + 2x^2\hat{j} + 2x^3z \ \hat k$$
I chose this specifically because this leads to some error.

And now I try to write scalar potential by writing $$\frac{\partial\phi_1}{\partial x} = 4xy-3x^2z^2$$ and integrating to get $$\phi_1 = 2x^2y-x^3z^2 + C_1$$ i.e. the scalar function from x part.

Similarly doing for $y$ and $z$ also.

Now final scalar potential will be $$\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 + C$$ with a final reduced constant. It will be $$\phi = 4xy-x^3z^2 -2x^3z + C$$

But when I try to get $\vec A$ again by taking the gradient of this function, it comes with some other terms too. Whats wrong here

Comment: Can a force vector always be written in terms of a potential, or does it need to satisfy certain conditions?

Comment: Please edit your question to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is the site standard for math expressions.

Comment: Hi Shikhar Chamoli. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @ShikharChamoli The edit history of your post clearly shows that your original question stated the problem as "\vectorA = (4xy-3x²z²)î + 2x²j + (2x³z)k.". In itself, this is not too serious, people make mistakes, but I see no point in drawing this out. And I certainly see no point in attacking Qmechanic unnecessarily, given the monumental amount of work they do for this site with little thanks.

Comment: Your question is not asking a question and giving an example, you're asking what is going wrong in your particular attempt to determine the scalar potential for this particular vector field. As we've seen, a simple + vs. - typo in the example can change the meaning of your question, since the answer you have already received becomes incorrect for the version with '-'.

Comment: The reason that the homework-and-exercises tag is used is because this question satisfies at least some of the criteria for that tag. Your question starts off as conceptual ("If we are given a vector function, can we directly write its associated scalar potential?") but as pointed out in ACuriousMind's comment, the rest of your question relies heavily on your example, including the last line that says "Is my method incorrect?" Now, this can be debated on [the meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/), but continuously rolling back moderators' edits is not going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

No it needs to be [conservative field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field). In three dimensions, this means the vector field must have 0 curl. Your example has curl $-(6x^2 + 4 xz )\hat{j}$.

Comment: Sorry @Bobak Hashemi sir, it was minus originally in the k components

Comment: @ShikharChamoli you don't just add up the terms, each of the $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, etc.. give necessary terms, its up to you to put them together into a total function $\phi$ that includes all necessary terms. The final answer (assuming you reverse the sign of the z term is) is $\phi = 2x^2 y - x^3 z^2 + C$